# Neet to create a custom action to execute a command in cmd prompt after installation of application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, custom-action

We're having a .Net application built on winforms and c#. We need to digitally sign the application exe after installation on any user's system. We've got the .pfx key and the installer exe is getting signed as expected when done manually in any system. Now we need to do this automatically right after the installation.

The installer exe file is generated in defined path in C drive and we provide the .pfx key along with the Dlls of application.

Tried creating custom action in visual studio but it is not triggering the cmd prompt as cmd is an external application.

I'm expecting a method / way to trigger cmd in background and run my command right after installation of application.

Comment: "Tried creating custom action in visual studio..." Can you show what you exactly tried? Post-build steps should definitely work.

Comment: you don't sign an assembly on installation, in particualr you *never* deploy your pfx-file. You need to do that during creation of your installer. Having said this you usually do something like `sn myassembly` as a postbuild-event in your release-buildd-pipeline, but never on clients machine.

Comment: You can automatically sign the application executable (exe) file after installation, and create a custom action in the installer that executes a command prompt (cmd) command in the background.